# How to change the location of strings inside the manipulate function?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, expression-manipulation

```
qmax[Dia_, Wt_, leff_, Rs_, Ks_, theta_, phi_, T_] := ((((((999.8995 + (16.9451*T) - ((7.987040*10^-3)*
           T^2) - ((46.170461*10^-6)*T^3) + ((105.56302*10^-9)*
           T^4) - ((280.54253*10^-12)*
           T^5))/(1 + (16.897850*10^-3)*T))*
     Ks*(3.14*Dia*
       Wt*10^-6))/(((0.02939*Exp[507.88/((T + 273) - 149.3)])/
       1000)*leff))*(((2*
       Cos[theta/
         57.2958]*((1 - 
           0.625*((647.15 - (T + 273))/
              647.15))*(235.8*10^-3)*(((647.15 - (T + 273))/
             647.15)^1.256))*10^3)/
     Rs) - ((999.8995 + (16.9451*T) - ((7.987040*10^-3)*
          T^2) - ((46.170461*10^-6)*T^3) + ((105.56302*10^-9)*
          T^4) - ((280.54253*10^-12)*T^5))/(1 + (16.897850*10^-3)*
         T))*9.81*leff*
    Sin[phi/57.2958]))*(2.5*10^6 - (2.386*10^3)*((T + 273) - 273)))  effl[Lp_, Lc_, Le_] := ((((Lc + Le)/2) + (Lp - Le - Lc))) Manipulate["Effective Length of Heat Pipe (mm):" <> 
ToString@Style[effl[Lp, Lc, Le], 14]Plot[ qmax[Dia, Wt, Leff, Rs, Ks, theta, phi, T], {Leff, 0, 0.5},
FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {{#, 1000 #} & /@ 
     FindDivisions[{0, 1}, 10] // N, Automatic}},
PlotLabel -> 
 Style["Maximum Heat Transfer Vs Effective Length", 
  FontSize -> 10, Bold, Black, 12],
PlotRange -> {0, 250},
PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Lighter[ Blue, 0.5]},
GridLines -> Automatic,
Frame -> True,
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12],
FrameLabel -> {Row[{Style["Effective Length of HP (mm)", Italic, 
     Bold, 11]}], 
  Row[{Style["Maximum Heat Transfer (W)", Italic, Bold, 11]}]},
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
ImageSize -> 400,
Background -> LightGreen,
GridLinesStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Blue], 
  Directive[Dashed, Red]}],Delimiter,Style["Dimensions of heat pipe", Italic, Bold, Blue, 13],{{Lp, 300, "Length of HP (mm) : "}, ControlType -> InputField,FieldSize -> 3}, {{Le, 150, "Length of Evaporator Section (mm) : "},ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 3},{{Lc, 150, "Length of Condenser Section (mm) : "},ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 3},{{Dia, 10 , "Tube Inner Diameter (mm) :"}, ControlType -> InputField,FieldSize -> 3},Delimiter,Style["Operating Temperature", Italic, Bold, Blue, 13],{{T, 100, "T (\[Degree]C): "}, ControlType -> InputField,FieldSize -> 3},Delimiter,Style["Wick Thickness", Italic, Bold, Blue, 13],{{Wt, 0.18, "Wt (mm) : "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 3},Delimiter,Style["Radius of the pore", Italic, Bold, Blue, 13],{{Rs, 0.02, "Rs (mm) : "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 3},Delimiter,Style["Permeability of Wick", Italic, Bold, Blue, 13],{{Ks, 0.302*10^-10, "Ks (m^2) : "}, ControlType -> InputField,FieldSize -> 6},Delimiter,Style["Weting angle", Italic, Bold, Blue, 13],{{theta, 0, "Angle in Degrees : "}, ControlType -> InputField,FieldSize -> 3},Delimiter,Style["Inclination angle", Italic, Bold, Blue, 13],{{phi, 30, "Angle in Degrees : "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 3},Delimiter,Item[Button["Display Graph", Nothing, BaseStyle -> {14},Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.5]]],LabelStyle -> {15},ContentSize -> 850,TrackedSymbols :> All,ControlPlacement -> Left,Frame -> True]
```

I am trying to build a dashboard for my group so that they can use that effectively for their analysis. But I want to do one change which I am not able to do. I need your help folks. I am displaying the value of "Effective Length of Heat Pipe (mm)" above the plot but I want to place it below the "Display Graph" button.

How I can move that string below the left-hand side. I don't want o display it above the plot. Please help me with this small change in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{"Effective Length of Heat Pipe (mm):" <> 
    ToString@Style[effl[Lp, Lc, Le], 14], 
   Plot[qmax[Dia, Wt, Leff, Rs, Ks, theta, phi, T], {Leff, 0, 0.5}, 
    FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {{#, 1000 #} & /@ 
         FindDivisions[{0, 1}, 10] // N, Automatic}}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style["Maximum Heat Transfer Vs Effective Length", 
      FontSize -> 10, Bold, Black, 12], PlotRange -> {0, 250}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Lighter[Blue, 0.5]}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], 
    FrameLabel -> {Row[{Style["Effective Length of HP (mm)", Italic, 
         Bold, 11]}], 
      Row[{Style["Maximum Heat Transfer (W)", Italic, Bold, 11]}]}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> 400, 
    Background -> LightGreen, 
    GridLinesStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Blue], 
      Directive[Dashed, Red]}]
   }, Alignment -> Center], Delimiter, 
 Style["Dimensions of heat pipe", Italic, Bold, Blue, 
  13], {{Lp, 300, "Length of HP (mm) : "}, ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 3}, {{Le, 150, "Length of Evaporator Section (mm) : "},
   ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 3}, {{Lc, 150, "Length of Condenser Section (mm) : "}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 3}, {{Dia, 10, "Tube Inner Diameter (mm) :"}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 3}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Operating Temperature", Italic, Bold, Blue, 
  13], {{T, 100, "T (\[Degree]C): "}, ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 3}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Wick Thickness", Italic, Bold, Blue, 
  13], {{Wt, 0.18, "Wt (mm) : "}, ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 3}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Radius of the pore", Italic, Bold, Blue, 
  13], {{Rs, 0.02, "Rs (mm) : "}, ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 3}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Permeability of Wick", Italic, Bold, Blue, 
  13], {{Ks, 0.302*10^-10, "Ks (m^2) : "}, ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 6}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Weting angle", Italic, Bold, Blue, 
  13], {{theta, 0, "Angle in Degrees : "}, ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 3}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Inclination angle", Italic, Bold, Blue, 
  13], {{phi, 30, "Angle in Degrees : "}, ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 3}, Delimiter, 
 Item[Button["Display Graph", Nothing, BaseStyle -> {14}, 
   Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.5]]], LabelStyle -> {15}, 
 ContentSize -> 850, TrackedSymbols :> All, ControlPlacement -> Left, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, @Alexei... I already did that but I want to display the string not on top of the graph but below the Display graph Button...

Comment: Or is it possible to put these strings separately from Plot?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Where precisely do you want to put it?

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand, what you have in mind. It is a bit difficult because the part of the code defining the button "Display graph" is outside of the body of the Manipulate statement. For this reason, you can put some static text above or below the button (using the same function `Column`) but the dynamic part of the text will not work.  There is a workaround. It consists in making a nested `Manipulate` statement. That is, one `Manipulate` inside the other. You need then to include the button "Display graph" into the inner `Manipulate` and wrap it by the `Column` statement with your text.

Comment: Continuation: All the other controls you can then include into the outer `Manipulate` statement. However, this will make your demonstration "heavy," and I would not recommend it.